# Type of '?:' if the first operand is a constant expression

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following code:

```
void f(float x)
{
    x * (true ? 1.f : 0.0);
}
```

The type of `declval(bool) ? declval(float) : declval(double)` is `double` according to the C++ standard [expr.cond].

Does this mean that the above code has to be equivalent to:

```
void f(float x)
{
    double(x) * 1.0;
}
```

Or is there a statement that allows an optimization in case the first operand of `?:` is a compile time constant expression ?

Comment: Is that from the `obfuscated c++ contest`? The `true ? 1.0f : ...` always evaluates to 1.0f, but does it make sense to multiply with 1.0f?

Comment: @ott-- That's a good way of wording the question in such a way that answers will focus only on what the question is really about. Pretty much any other constant would likely get answers focusing on rounding, even though that isn't the point of the question.

Comment: An expression can always only have one type, so the type of `something ? a : b` will and must always be the same, no matter what `something` is.

Comment: It's not equivalent to your second code example, it's equivalent to `x * 1.0`, which has type `double`, there is no cast back to `float`

Comment: @Xeo An expression that has a dependent type can have different types in different template instantiations. (I know you know this, and that you didn't mean to suggest otherwise.)

Comment: This question is all about types; there is nothing about value category as all the relevant subexpressions are prvalues.

Comment: @BenVoigt I meant that if in one template instantiation `a` and `b` are `int`, and in another instantiation `a` and `b` are `long`, `something ? a : b` doesn't always have the same type.

Comment: @hvd: While that's true, it's completely off-topic for this discussion.

Comment: @BenVoigt It was a response to the claim "so the type of `something ? a : b` will and must always be the same", which is not entirely correct, even if what I think Xeo meant by it is.

Comment: @hvd: He said "no matter what `something` is", which is correct.  Actually, not even changing the type of `something` will have any effect, since it's always converted to `bool` in that context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A C++ compiler can optimize as it sees fit, provided that it does not alter the "observable behaviour" of a conforming program (§1.9p1, the so-called "as if" rule).

For example, if on a given platform it is known that multiplying by 1.0 is an identity transformation without the potential to trap, then the multiplication does not actually need to be performed. (This may or may not be true for a given architecture, since it is possible that multiplying a NaN value by 1.0 could trap. However, the compiler could also replace the multiplication by any other operation which would produce the same trap under the same circumstances.)

In the absence of traps and assuming that multiplication by 1.0 is an identity transform, the entire body of your function `f` can be eliminated, because the standard requires that the set of `float` values is a subset of the set of `double` values (possibly the same set). Consequently, the float->double->float round trip must return to the original value or trap. (§3.9.1p8: "The set of values of the type `float` is a subset of the set of values of the type `double`". §4.8p1: "A prvalue of floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of another floating point type. If the source value can be exactly represented in the destination type, the result of the conversion is that exact representation.")

So, yes, optimizations may be possible. But that does not affect the type of the `?:` expression, in the case that the type is observable (for example, if the expression were to be used for template deduction or as the operand of `decltype`).

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it does mean that the above codes are equivalent.

Using [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) we can check that at least both `clang` and `g++` are standard conformant and give `d` (e.g. double) as an output to this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main() {
    float x = 3.;
    auto val = x * (true ? 1.f : 0.0);
    std::cout << typeid(val).name() << std::endl;
}
```

And the alternative way using C++11 [type traits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main() {
    float x = 3.;
    auto val = x * (true ? 1.f : 0.0);
    std::cout << std::boolalpha <<
        std::is_same<decltype(val), double>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Outputs `true`.